# Python BeautifulSoup4 getting string info from a tag inside h1 tag

Tags: html, python-3.x, tags, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

im trying to get the string information that's inside an a tag, but the a tag is inside a h1 tag.

```
<h1 class="branded-page-header-title">
      <span class="qualified-channel-title ellipsized"><span class="qualified-channel-title-wrapper"><span dir="ltr" class="qualified-channel-title-text" ><a dir="ltr" href="/user/viralvideoslmao" class="spf-link branded-page-header-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink" title="ViralVideos" data-sessionlink="ei=lXIIVM-_CvKQigahpIHgDA"      >ViralVideos</a></span></span></span>
    </h1>
```

I want the info that in this case is 'ViralVideos'
a.t.m I have this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_yt_links():
    url = "https://youtube.com"
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for code in soup.findAll('a'):
        href = "http://youtube.com" + code.get('href')
        if "channel/U" in href:
            get_user(href)
            print(href)

def get_user(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for user in soup.findAll('h1', {'class': 'branded-page-header-title'}).a:
        print(user.string)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have now is that `findAll()` returns a list of results, and there is no `a` attribute on a list.

To get the `a` tag, you can use [`CSS selectors`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and check for the class names of `h1` and `a` tags:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for link in soup.select('h1.branded-page-header-title a.branded-page-header-title-link'):
    print link.text
```

For the HTML you've provided it prints `ViralVideos`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `find_all` to `find`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
print soup.find('h1', {'class': 'branded-page-header-title'}).a.text
```

Comment: The problem is - we don't know if there is only one `h1` with the `branded-page-header-title` class and we don't know how many `a` tags are there inside. The example the OP provided is just a small part of a bigger picture.